# Calling an API to run the code in the background

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, hosting

I have a node.js backend program that needs to be run by calling only the API. It doesn't have frontend or UI. The program is accessing my local machine for some excel files to be uploaded in the client's database.

In my local machine, I tried calling the API, (localhost:4000/${my_route}), through postman and the program successfully run. But when I uploaded my source code in Heroku and tried to run the created application by calling the API, ([https://word-word-number.herokuapp.com/${my_route}](https://word-word-number.herokuapp.com/$%7Bmy_route%7D)), it doesn't work.

The expectation is, the client will just call the hosted API so that their excel files which is stored on their machine will go to their database.

Do you have any ideas where to host the application and how to call the API?

Update: Here is my index.js[image]

Comment: The fact that there is no frontend is not an issue, it can still be deployed on heroku and used like you do it in your local environment. The issue here is more likely that your app has not been deployed correctly, or that some things in your code needs to be adapted to work on heroku. Please provide the code of your index.ts if you want more help on this

Comment: Already uploaded my index.js. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get error messages? What do your logs say? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't allow you to choose a port so you should probably get it from the environmental variables.

Let's say you are using express you should do something like this

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Already updated my question. I am using that for my port.

Comment: when do you say that by calling the Heroku endpoint it doesn't work you mean that your application is not running or that it's not doing what you expect?

Comment: The heroku application is running but it not doing what is expected. But when I replaced the heroku app to localhost:4000, the code runs perfectly.

Comment: how does the application retrieve the excel file you are talking about?

Comment: There's a function that reads the file path using fs.readdir(folderPath) and search that path if there is a files in that path and retrieves the fileName. If there is, there's a function that loops through the files in the folder path and then XLSX package will read using XLSX.readFile(`folderPath\\${fileName}`) for every file.

Comment: (sry for late response) Does heroku have these files you are trying to retrive tho?
You should let your users upload the files on your api so that it can process them.
For what you said in the question it doesnt look like you are doing so.